# return dynamically created function

Tags: python, lambda, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to create a function that takes multiple arguments, and returns a callable lambda function. I'm passing these lambda functions into BeautifulSoup's `find_all` method in order to parse html.

Here is the function I've written to generate the lambda functions:

```
def tag_filter_function(self, name="", search_terms={}, attrs=[], **kwargs):

    # filter attrs that are in the search_terms keys out of attrs
    attrs = [attr for attr in attrs if attr not in search_terms.keys()]

    # array of strings to compile into a lambda function
    exec_strings = []

    # add name search into exec_strings
    if len(name) > 0:
        tag_search_name = "tag.name == \"{}\"".format(name)
        exec_strings.append(tag_search_name)

    # add generic search terms into exec_strings
    if len(search_terms) > 0:
        tag_search_terms = ' and '.join(["tag.has_attr(\"{}\") and tag[\"{}\"] == \"{}\"".format(k, k, v) for k, v in search_terms.items()])
        exec_strings.append(tag_search_terms)

    # add generic has_attr calls into exec_strings
    if len(attrs) > 0:
        tag_search_attrs = ' and '.join(["tag.has_attr(\"{}\")".format(item) for item in attrs])
        exec_strings.append(tag_search_attrs)

    # function string
    exec_string = "lambda tag: " + " and ".join(exec_strings)

    return exec(compile(exec_string, '<string>', 'exec'))
```

The function string that returns from calling

```
tag_filter_function(name="article", search_terms={"id" : "article"})
```

is

```
lambda tag: tag.name == "article" and tag.has_attr("id") and tag["id"] == "article"
```

The function's return value is `None`. I'm not convinced that the `exec()` function is what I want to use here, but I'm really not sure. Is converting this string into an executable lambda function possible, and if so how? Not sure that I'm going about this the right way.

Comment: If you're using `has_attr` on the tag, shouldn't you look for `tag.attr` rather than `tag[attr]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is absolutely no need to use exec. To return a function from a function, just define a new function and return it. E.g.

```
def outer_function():
    def inner_function():
        something_here
    return inner_function
```

In your case, it looks like you want to do something like this:

```
def tag_filter_function(self, name="", search_terms={}, attrs=[], **kwargs):

    # filter attrs that are in the search_terms keys out of attrs
    attrs = [attr for attr in attrs if attr not in search_terms.keys()]

    def f(tag):

        # add name search into exec_strings
        if len(name) > 0:
            if tag.name != name:
                return False

        # add generic search terms into exec_strings
        if len(search_terms) > 0:
            if not all(tag.has_attr(k) and tag[k] == v
                   for k, v in search_terms.items()):
                return False

        # add generic has_attr calls into exec_strings
        if len(attrs) > 0:
            if not all(tag.has_attr(item) for item in attrs):
                return False

        return True

    return f
```

Comment: People have different preferences, but I think `functools.partial` works even better than nesting functions.

Comment: @DSM Yes, `functools.partial` would be an interesting approach, if you really want to avoid nesting. And it does have some benefits, like having just one instance of the "inner" function, but I like nesting :)

Comment: Great answer (mine tended to solve the OP's specific question while your is better because it educates about a better way to approach the problem altogether). I think you may want to edit your answer to make the returned function depend on an argument `tag` as the OP requires.

Comment: Thanks @zvone, extremely helpful suggestions. Your answer worked perfectly within my use case. Thanks again.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to make the smallest change to your code, you could simply try:

```
return eval(exec_string)
```

but for a better approach to solve your problem, you should follow zvone's suggestion and re-formulate the approach altogether by returning a function.